# Scheduling semantic of a task in Verilog

Tags: verilog

The execution of this code under iverilog simulator

```
module top();
    reg clk;
    reg[31:0] counter;
    reg[19:0] in;
    reg[31:0] out;
    reg[19:0] xxx;
    reg[19:0] yyy;

    always #5 clk = ~clk;

    initial begin
        clk <= 0;
        counter <= 0;
        out <= 0;
    end

    always @(posedge(clk)) begin
        decode_inst(counter);
        $strobe("pre-counter is %0t",counter);
        counter = counter + 1;
        out <= counter;
        $strobe("time is %0t",$time);
        $strobe("counter is %0t",counter);
        $strobe("out is %0t",out);
        decode_inst(counter);
        if (counter == 2) $finish();
    end
    
    task decode_inst(input xxx);
        begin
             $strobe("task_time is %0t",$time);
             $strobe("task_counter is %0t",xxx);
        end
    endtask  
endmodule
```

produces the following output:

```
task_time is 5
task_counter is 1
pre-counter is 1
time is 5
counter is 1
out is 1
task_time is 5
task_counter is 1
task_time is 15
task_counter is 0
pre-counter is 2
time is 15
counter is 2
out is 2
task_time is 15
task_counter is 0
```

Even studing the semantic of Verilog scheduling,

I'm not able to explain to myself the result.
In particular, how it is possible

task_counter = 0 when task_time = 15 and

task_counter = 1 when task_time = 5.

My question: is this output compliant with Verilog scheduling semantic?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior described in the post is compliant with Verilog and its scheduling semantics.
The unexpected behavior (task_counter = 0 at the end) is caused by an error in the task argument.
The argument type is omitted; the default type is one-bit wide.
One bit can't represent the integer 2.
To correct this, change the task argument type to a vector as below:

```
task decode_inst(input [31:0] xxx);
    begin
      $strobe("task_time is %0t",$time);
      $strobe("task_counter is %0d",xxx);
    end
endtask
```

Also added some time after the clock to let the printing occur before the simulation ends.  Without this the test is stopping and printing at the same time which can be confusing and lead to figuring out who wins the race.
Add #1 delay:

```
if (counter == 2) #1 $finish();
```

Produces the result in two simulators on EDA Playground:

```
# pre-counter is 1
# time is 5
# counter is 1
# out is 1
# task_time is 5
# task_counter is 1
# pre-counter is 2
# time is 15
# counter is 2
# out is 2
# task_time is 15
# task_counter is 2
```